# how to remove warning when retrieving for 1 value only from the database using array_values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, warnings

I am trying to get only one column of data from database and here is my code in php (Please take note that `$prno` is unique in pr table)

```
$prid = array_values(mysqli_fetch_array($conn->query("SELECT id from pr where pr_no = '$prno'")))[0];
```

However, I always get this warning below:

> Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\listframe.php on line 28

Can anyone please help me remove the warning or could anyone have a better workaround for this?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.